# Mongoose - How to query within an hook?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm not 100% sure about how to formulate this question.

Consider the following code of the 'message.js' model file.

I have a "post remove" hook in which I query the User collection, which is defined in the user.js file (That file is pretty much the same as this one).

Now, what I'd like to do is to query the Message collection(which is defined in this file) inside the "pre save" hook.

Is it possible to do that ?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = require('./user');

var schema = new Schema({
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

schema.post('remove', function (message) {
    User.findById(message.user, function (err, user) {
        user.messages.pull(message);
        user.save();
    });
});

schema.pre('save', function(next) {

  //Here I want to query the Message collection

  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {

    let MessageModel = mongoose.model('Message');

    MessageModel.find(findQuery, (err, results) => {
        if(err) handleError();

        //Do stuff with results
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why query can hang inside hooks, not ever reaching callbacks?